# Can we request DevDays topics?

Tags: discussion, devdays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What topics would you like to learn at DevDays 2011?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/what-topics-would-you-like-to-learn-at-devdays-2011)

I am currently knee deep in trying to replace some proprietary code with various Apache projects like Hadoop, Lucene, Nutch and/or Solr, and I'd really love it if somebody who knew something about these subjects could be lined up to speak at the Toronto Dev Days.  Is Joel just going to choose the topics himself, or can we request them?

(If the answer is yes, we can request them, then I or somebody else should start a CW question for requests, right?)

Answer (score 1):

For DevDays 2011, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/what-topics-would-you-like-to-learn-at-devdays-2011) to request topics.