# What topics would you like to learn at DevDays 2011?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2011

Here's a very brief summary of how [Stack Overflow DevDays](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com) 2011 will go down:

1. It'll be [two days long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86663/devdays-2011-straw-poll-one-day-or-two).
2. It'll be sometime in September or October.
3. There will be FOUR independent, separate events to choose from in different cities: [London](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/london/), [Washington DC](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/washington-dc/), [San Francisco](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/san-francisco/), and [Sydney](http://devdays.stackoverflow.com/sydney/).
4. There will be a single track, so you never have to worry about choosing between two equally cool topics.

When we did DevDays 2009, the idea was to do some intensive, one hour programming tutorials on the kinds of topics that we thought a lot of programmers really wanted to learn, but didn't have a chance yet to use at work. Two years ago, the topics we tried to cover were jQuery, Python, iPhone development, ASP.NET MVC, Google App Engine, etc.

This year, we've got two days, so there'll be time for even more sessions. We'll also have time for deeper, more big-picture talks in between the tutorials.

What topics would you like to learn about at DevDays 2011? One topic per answer, please, and vote up all the ones you like.

**UPDATE (April 21st)** Thanks for all the feedback, ideas, and votes so far. Keep it coming! We are working on nailing down dates and venues. Soon, we will line up committees for each city responsible for lining up speakers and fleshing out the schedule: they'll use this input as guidance to set up an awesome program in each of the four venues.

In the meantime *if you have other questions about DevDays or other discussion, please ask it as a separate question tagged devdays-2011, don't just leave a random fly-by comment in the comments*.

Comment: No chance of a central location (like New Orleans)?

Comment: I was definitely holding out for another Canadian stop, but I guess the guys down under luck in this time.

Comment: Just one thing - will it be available as Live webcast ? I'm outside US or AU :(

Comment: And one more thing will Jon Skeet and his Tony the Pony will be there this time too.... (I miss tony a lot ;)

Comment: if only there were a q&a site, where you could ask questions, and get answers... and people could, you know, vote on those answers, and... OH WAIT! THERE IS! **Plz 2 ask all follow-up q's using the ASK QUESTION button and then typing. kthx**

Comment: Can you guys push it later? I'm kind of getting married in September ;-) Unless I can convince my future wife to honeymoon at DevDays ... (just kidding!!!)

Comment: Any chance of some open space sessions at these events? The best parts of the last conference were the discussions between sessions and afterwards. The topics at the DC event were hit and miss. If you want info/advice on running these talk to the PyCon folks like Bruce Eckel as they run them really well, compared to those I've seen at .NET events.

Comment: Why not just create a question for each venue and allow session submissions in the answers. Highest voted submissions get in. Simple as.

Comment: @PhilPursglove I'm not sure I'd bother going to the conference if that was the case. I can understand why DVCS is leading below, but I don't think that it necessarily makes for the best presentation or conference content. It would need to cover material above and beyond the likes of the hg init tutorial.

Comment: @BrianLy *"The topics at the DC event were hit and miss"* This is likely the biggest reason they are 1) holding fewer events and 2) forming committees to determine the topics and speakers.

Comment: @adam - the reason there are fewer events is because of the tremendous amount of time and energy it takes to do a venue/event.  They are delegating the work and looking for an easier way to find/determine topics.  It has nothing to do with "hit and miss"

Comment: @Tim That makes sense.

Comment: @Cade Are you based in the US by any chance? A *central location* based on London, US East Coast, US West Coast, and Australia would be near the Earth's core. It might present practical difficulties.

Comment: Still trying to learn this site. Can anyone explain how this question is on topic for this site?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

## Node.js

[Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and other uses of JavaScript on the server.

Comment: I don't have enough points tu upvote this, but I'd really like to hear more about Node.js!

Answer (score 138):

## HTML 5

"HTML 5" applications (offline web apps, local storage, etc.) would probably be a good candidate.

Answer (score 138):

## Distributed Version Control Systems

Git, Mercurial, etc. Advantages/disadvantages over CVS/SVN, examples of workflows, tools, social coding ([GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/), etc.).

Comment: By the way, for London DevDays 2011, I can make a presentation on how to introduce a DVCS in a big corporation: I can easily expand on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683253/distributed-version-control-systems-and-the-enterprise-a-good-mix/5685757#5685757

Comment: I can see how examples of workflows and/or integration with other tools might be good fodder for sessions. However I've been to one too many DVCS tutorials and presentations along those lines would be boring.

Comment: I downvoted this. Nothing personal!!! I really like DVCS, but I've read a bit about it already, played around with Mercurial (love it!), but I don't feel like I can get my organization to swiftly remove our TFS infrastructure and replace it with Mercurial. Learning even more about DVCS wouldn't, I don't think, change my mind.

Comment: @BrianLy: nothing boring about such a session: this is very practical, and tackles authentication, authorization but also workflow and integration with existing tools/IDE. @Pandicus: true  (I have the same scenario with IBM RTC Rational Team Concert). My presentation would also draw a contrast between TFS or RTC and DVCS like Git or Mercurial.

Comment: @Pandincus: Same here, but I really would like to know how to move your company forward, getting them to accept DCVS instead of old SVN/CVS systems. So I voted this one up.

Comment: I don't see how this is worth making into a devdays session - there are plenty of resources online about this.  I agree with the others - this is not worth doing.

Comment: @tim: "there are plenty of resources online about this": no there are not, not on the topic I propose, which is about the particular challenges you will face when introducing a DVCS in a big corporation.

Comment: @VonC - You are better off with a consultant to address your particular needs than expecting a devdays to address those.  I repeat - there are plenty of resources online to address the content in your question's text.  You may have some things in mind that are not in the question - but this is not really a topic that is really that compelling.  If you can't convince your team(s) of DVCS with the content already out there then a 2 hour presentation from DevDays is not going ot help either.  Just because it is (still) the latest shiny thing doesn't mean it is good for devdays in general.

Comment: @tim: this is not about convincing the team (they hardly need convincing most of the time ;) ) This is about taking into account the particular needs of a big corporation, compared to what a DVCS in general can offer. I am very much interested by those "plenty of resources online" you keep referring to, because I didn't find that many when I did my setup, migration and introduction of a DVCS in my large company.

Answer (score 112):

## Deployment

One of the more challenging situations we encounter (in our very small shop) is deploying new versions of software smoothly. I hear a lot about **one-click deployment**, **build automation**, and **continuous integration**, but I'd like to learn more.

Perhaps one or more of the following topics could be discussed:

- Package management (*OK, maybe the NuGet answer covers this*)
- Build servers/build automation
- Configuration file/connection string management
- One-click deployment/'Continuous Deployment'
- Database versioning/upgrading to newer schema/downgrading to older schema

Comment: I like this topic there are a lot of things that can be explored, and it is not as mundane as some may think.

Comment: @BrianLy - Thanks! After all, what good is fancy software if you have trouble deploying it ;-)

Comment: WIX! I would love to see some love for WIX!

Comment: RedGate SQL Source Control FTW!

Comment: I'd love to see some coverage of the excellent [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.0/index.html) tool for Python deployment.

Answer (score 87):

## Leaving the mothership

I'd like to hear from people who left their day job and started a one-man-shop or a bigger company.  What's the important stuff to get right?  War stories would be great.  An entertaining break from the technical side of programming.

Comment: Perhaps we could hear about talking to corporate, approving memos, leading workshops, remembering birthdays, micromanagement, and promoting synergy. Like a boss.

Comment: @Pandincus: Hehe, I meant starting for yourself, not becoming a pointy haired boss :)

Comment: @Andomar - I know, I was just kidding ;-) I like the topic idea.

Comment: If I'm out on my own, who will I submit my TPS report to?!

Comment: Or even turning your job into an internal "one man shop" - sometimes the corporate life can be more livable if you work more like an entrepreneur.

Comment: I think this and other similar topics would be good for a "Business of software, lite" - but perhaps not for a devdays.  I think the goal is technical topics.

Comment: You could ask Leon the SecretGeek, he has done this and [speaks on the subject](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast47HowToStartYourOwnMicroISV.aspx)

Comment: I've started my own company with my Brother(Programmer) and Dad(PM) building iPhone apps, Web apps, and interactive (openFrameworks etc). It was inspired heavily from the management episode of this developers life. We're about halfway to breaking even in 3-6 months. Would love to help anyone else who was in the position I was (Stuck in dedicated project management). Could probably put together a little talk on it all, maybe share the spot with a few others that have done the same?

Answer (score 82):

## Scalability

How to design web applications for scalability. Things to avoid in order to not shoot yourself in the foot later. Using "[The Cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing#History)" (Amazon EC2, etc.).

Maybe off-topic for Stack Overflow.. perhaps more Server Fault related, but figured I'd throw it out there and let the community decide.

Answer (score 79):

## Android Development

Honeycomb, Android on tablets, etc.

Answer (score 74):

## Programming Best Practices

While a lot of folks on Stack Overflow are experienced developers, I'm sure there's quite a few who are newcomers to the field and are still learning. A good topic might be an overview of some industry best practices to make the event more open to newcomers, and to perhaps give folks still in school some insights into real world problems/solutions which they might not normally learn at school.

A quick list of things that spring to mind:

- SQL injection - What is it? Why is it bad? How to prevent it?
- Version control - Why you should use it, systems available, single vs distributed, etc.
- Internationalization - Unicode, why it's not as simple as it first seems, etc.
- Encryption - Why it's bad to roll your own, etc.
- Unit testing - Why it's important, how it helps, etc.

As the event is single track, the downside would be that it would be of little use for experienced programmers whom I imagine would make up a significant portion of the audience.

Comment: As you note, the people whom this *should* concern won't be in the audience.

Comment: Dumbing down a conference is not a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: +1 [Tony the pony (Jon Skeet)](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) presented on this at the London DevDay. I couldn't make it but the [slides](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) look awesome. I have some colleagues who could benefit from this.

Comment: @MarkJ Indeed, this is exactly the type of thing I had in mind. Jon Skeet's talk was my favourite of DevDays back in 09, yet it was about such "simple" topics we all take for granted (numbers, strings and time). There's no reason why a talk about best practices can't work if done properly.

Comment: I bet that there will be a lot of people there that think they don't need this kind of training but actually do. Just because you have been coding for ten years doesn't mean you are any good at it. I think it is sad that the software industry is so focused on the next technology that they never talk about ways to improve quality.

Answer (score 64):

### UI design for engineers,

#### or working *with* UI designers *as* an engineer

Comment: +1 for the first part, as some of us work where we don't have separate UI designers ...

Answer (score 63):

## Hadoop

[MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), [HBase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HBase), [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra), [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/), etc. How are they useful? When should they be used?

Answer (score 63):

## CSS3

What new things can be done in CSS3, etc.

Answer (score 57):

### Writing a compiler or interpreter (or even plain old parsing)

This is something that a lot of people do in a CS course. For a lot of programmers who did not study CS it is scary, but interesting at the same time.

Since this is such a huge topic there are various ways it could be approached. Examples:

- Basic howto with some working example that attendees can explore after the event.
- Pick apart an existing compiler or interpreter like IronPython.
- Review some common language features and how they are implemented in different compilers or runtimes.
- Look into how a DSL can be created.
- How to build a SQL parser with a popular language.
- How parsing techniques can be used outside of a traditional compiler/interpreter to make life easier.
- How does a browser parse and display HTML.

Comment: +1 Especially for the last one... since we know it doesn't use RegEx :P

Comment: Gold Parser or ANTLR would be a really interesting topic - I'm sure Terence Parr would do a talk as he's just finished a book he's trying to promote on ANTLR

Comment: There's a reason compilers are an entire undergraduate or graduate course - they are a huge area.  This would have to be pretty focused.

Answer (score 47):

### Search

Search in heterogeneous data, [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene), [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr), and whatever the cool kids use.

Answer (score 38):

## F#

F# is getting lots of [attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734525/getting-started-with-f)

Answer (score 37):

## iPhone/iPad development

Answer (score 35):

### Patterns and practices for functional programming

I would love to learn more about patterns for functional development. I've always enjoyed playing with functional languages (Common Lisp back in the day, now Mathematica and Clojure), but I always find that as soon as I dive into larger projects, the code turns into a mess. From someone who's developed large, functional code bases: what are some good practices? What does it "feel" like to write large functional code bases?

Answer (score 35):

## C++11

(Formerly known as C++0x)

I want to know about the new features and changes/additions to the standard library.

Comment: Actually, it's officially C++11 now (although I don't find the link anymore).

Comment: @fretje, see I didn't even know that! I really need a seminar :)

Comment: It was Boris Jabes who said it in this talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays020

Answer (score 34):

## [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: +1 - I had never even heard of jQuery Mobile until I saw it here.

Comment: That's a very interesting topic for me, also as a speaker. Actually anything jQuery-related.

Answer (score 30):

## ASP.NET MVC 3

Would love to see some stuff on this.

Comment: [Here you go ;-)](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11?sort=viewed&direction=asc&term=&t=mvc#tab_sortBy_viewed)

Comment: lots of available online content for this, I recommend the MIX11 links

Answer (score 29):

## Advanced Topics in Computer Science

A survey of interesting "latest and greatest" issues that are being explored but haven't quite hit the main stream yet, or are just starting to get attention, or that are not being leveraged fully yet. For example GPU computing, multicore computing, or scientific computing clusters might be a topic.

This might not be a good area to work on for side-topics or break out sessions, but I could see at least one main topic being presented as part of the regular main sessions. Additionally, if you have a limited number of locations for travel, you might also be able to get someone from a local university to come in and give a presentation on a topic.

Answer (score 23):

## Django web framework

And maybe [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/).

Answer (score 22):

## MonoTouch and Mono for Android

Comment: If it still exists by then :( http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/is-mono-dead-is-novell-dying/8821

Answer (score 21):

## [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org)

This seems to be the clear winner for document oriented databases.

Answer (score 20):

### RavenDB (and/or other document databases like CouchDB)

Comment: Basically NoSQL. +1

Comment: It is a part of NoSQL. There are other types like KV stores and graph databases. Covering all of NoSQL is too broad a session type, unless you can go beyond the stuff that can be looked up in 5 minutes on Wikipedia. This is the type of thing that might work better as a panel discussion with people sitting in different camps (relational vs. nosql, or couchdb vs. redis vs. cassandra etc)

Answer (score 19):

## Comet

Successful stories, bottlenecks, pros and cons for [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 19):

**Distributed cache (Memcached, AppFabric Cache), search (Lucene, Solr).**

Answer (score 18):

**Concurrency / Parallel Computation**

Processors are no longer getting significantly faster, just more numerous.  Knowing how to take advantage of multi-core machines and computing clusters is going to be a valuable skill.

There is an alphabet soup of technologies out there:  AMP, SMP, MPP, NUMA, GPGU, CUDA, OpenCL, etc.  Effective programmers will have to be conversant in these, plus thread saftey, synchronization mechanizms, cache interactions, and more.

Let's have some help figuring out how to turn our serial processes into parallel ones.

Answer (score 16):

### Practical cross-platform development

Possible topics:

- Virtualization for testing, builds, development
- Licensing/copy protection across multiple platforms
- Continuous integration while building for multiple platforms
- Best practices and best tools (e.g. useful debugging and profiling tools for each platform)
- UI frameworks for cross platform development

Answer (score 15):

## PhoneGap

and other frameworks for developing mobile applications.

Answer (score 13):

## Entity Framework

[Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) and in particular the new code-first bits.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript 1.8.5+ (ECMAScript 5)

along  with HTML5

Answer (score 12):

## CoffeeScript

When I noticed that two of the smartest developers I knew were (independently) running around converting all of their existing, perfectly functional JavaScript to [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) I realized this was the Next Big Thing.

Answer (score 11):

## Leveraging NuGet

My fantasy is that you can create a new solution, slap in a bunch of packages via NuGet, and have a fully functioning application that does everything you need, without writing a single line of code.

I'd like to see how close to reality this is.

Comment: That's one depraved fantasy you've got

Comment: @Chris: They're [getting quite close already](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix/mix11/key01#time=0h52m44s)...

Answer (score 11):

## Scalability and Performance Optimization

Some kind of a practical case study of a bunch of things done to improve the scalability of a successful application.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88052/what-topics-would-you-like-to-learn-at-devdays-2011/88221#88221

Answer (score 11):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)

Scala is a general purpose programming language designed to express common programming patterns in a concise, elegant, and type-safe way. It smoothly integrates features of object-oriented and functional languages, enabling Java and other programmers to be more productive. Code sizes are typically reduced by a factor of two to three when compared to an equivalent Java application.

Answer (score 10):

## WPF

It's funny how almost no other answers here have touched the good old desktop app. Though it does seem like a dying breed this day and age, I think there's still a niche for that, and WPF brings a lot of potential to the interface side. It would be interesting to find out more about it.

Comment: And MVVM, of course.

Answer (score 9):

## Automating JavaScript unit testing and performance profiling

Workflow patterns to manage JavaScript testing and performance in large scale web applications. As more and more applications are leveraging JavaScript to build rich UIs, it becomes increasingly important to treat JavaScript testing as equally important as the server side code testing you are (hopefully) doing.

I was thinking along the lines of:

**Automated testing** - using [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29), [WatiN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir#Similar_tools)/[Watir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir) and [TestSwarm](http://swarm.jquery.org/) to execute JavaScript unit tests and capture results

**Performance profiling tools** - e.g. [JSLitmus](http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/), [dynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/application-performance-management-solutions.aspx), etc. again, perhaps using Selenium/WatiN/Watir to execute and capture performance results..

**Code quality tools** - e.g. [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint), [jQueryLint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/), etc.

**Unit testing and Acceptance Testing frameworks** e.g. [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit), [JsUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSUnit), [RhinoUnit](http://code.google.com/p/rhinounit/), [JSSpec](http://code.google.com/p/jsspec/), [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) etc.

Answer (score 8):

## Knockout js

[Knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/): Declarative bindings, automatic UI refresh, dependency tracking, templating.

Answer (score 8):

You can't ever go wrong with

## Miguel De Icaza

Comment: Try asking Attachmate about that...

Answer (score 8):

## Game development

It's no fun to spend all day talking about boring business apps and webpages (ok, so maybe it is... but still). Let's have some entertainment geek-style. A lecture about game development would be nice, especially with examples and tips on starting your own game. Technologies like XNA and Flash could be represented.

Answer (score 8):

## Windows Phone 7 Development

Possible topics:

- Silverlight
- XNA game development
- Service integration with [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Answer (score 7):

**Google Closure Compiler & Library**

- Developing reusable UI components
- Nested UI controls
- How to mix with legacy code (especially homegrown code, not just jQuery and Prototype)
- Real-world case studies
- Tips, tricks and best practices

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript MVC Frameworks

For example:

- [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)
- [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)
- [JavaScript MVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)
- etc.

Answer (score 5):

## AJAX

and other web technologies.

Comment: Wow, do I know how to pick them or what?

Comment: I don't know much about AJAX so I'd be interested to know, why the downvotes?

Comment: @War, yeah, I don't know much about it either which is why I brought it up.

Comment: You can be much more specific than AJAX. Is there a specific library or thing that you are interested in doing with AJAX? Just posting the term is not good enough in this case because AJAX is an established technology. With some more context you'll probably fair better. This is a problem with a lot of the items posted here to be honest.

Comment: @BrianLy, I agree with you specific is better, but since I don't know anything about it, I can only ask for the general case.

Comment: You could join up with the javascript one above... maybe add jQuery to the mix as well.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell)

Haskell has been getting a lot of attention in the programming language community for a while now.  Its pure nature makes it decent at concurrent tasks, and its threading model is faster than [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/) and [Go](http://golang.org) while being evented in a fashion not unlike [Node.js](http://nodejs.org). Especially recently there have been a lot of [Haskell](http://snapframework.com/) [web](http://www.yesodweb.com/) [frameworks](http://happstack.com/index.html) popping up.  It would be very interesting for the community at large to get a better perspective on this "emerging" technology.

Answer (score 5):

## [Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/)

Erlang's actor model is of particular interest, as are the constraint of immutable data and the error detection among processes. The ease of handling binary messages is a bonus. Though Scala also supplies the Actor model, it would be more motivating to learn about this high profile, battle tested solution. Erlang is used by many high profile companies, such as [Amazon, Yahoo, Facebook, T-Mobile, Motorola, and, of course, Ericsson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636455/where-is-erlang-used-and-why/1637137#1637137).

Answer (score 5):

## Coding on GPU's

Choices, benefits, examples, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**The latest from Rob Conery.**

Now it's WebMatrix and "writing SQL is cool again", by the time of the conference, it'll be "Hibernate, big frameworks, big tools, with CVS is the only way".

Comment: ha, it would definitely be fun ; )

Answer (score 4):

### [Lift](http://liftweb.net/)

Scala web framework.

Comment: +1 This and Scala need more votes!

Answer (score 4):

## The best ways to ensure your team isn't writing insecure code

When deadlines are tight or you have junior developers often security concerns don't get the attention they deserve. Also some security holes are obscure and even experienced developers don't always notice they are creating them. What processes can be put in place to ensure that software is as secure as it can be.

The latest fiasco with Sony's PlayStation Network show that even multinational corporations still can't get this right.

Answer (score 3):

## Debugging UserScripts

UserScript usage is increasing and debugging them is a real challenge.

Comment: what is UserScript? Greasemonkey scripts?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, UserScripts and Greasemonkey scripts are virtually identical.

Answer (score 3):

**[Manos de Mono](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos)** and scalable web service development for .NET without ASP.NET/IIS/Apache.

Comment: I'd love maybe a whirlwind tour of open source / alternative .net web servers (e.g. Nancy + Manos + i think there's some others)

Answer (score 3):

### Drupal

Cover what's new in Drupal 7.

How to deploy sites quick, maintain and customize content, develop new functionality using modules and themes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

### It's an app app app app world!

A talk that goes through the industry shift to the large app stores.  Developed by the phone industry, co-opted and made popular by Apple, and now moving to PCs via the Mac and upcoming Windows stores.

- What does this mean for developers?
- Review of existing and upcoming stores:

  - Process
  - Policy
  - Pricing
- How can developers leverage this change to their advantage?
- ...?

Comment: There are answers requesting android and iOS development on the top of this list.

Comment: @Moshe This would be less about a specific platform, and more about an industry trend.  I don't think programmers really understand how this really changes the industry.  It's akin to the change from procedural programming to object oriented programming.  While you can still operate as you normally do, I suspect there's some value to trying to understand where the industry is headed in order to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3):

**Internet of things**

The Internet of things is coming on strong with what seems like every device on the planet getting an IP address. How do we plan for and develop for this new world?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Answer (score 3):

### jQuery Ajax best practices

jQuery Ajax best practices, if possible, for .NET.

Answer (score 3):

### Artificial Intelligence

A talk covering current AI trends, or *the basics* of [GA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)s, neural networks, search, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Right tool for the right job**

(I'm bringing Java in here since this is my day-to-day language but maybe this can be expanded to other languages/platforms)
This is a discussion around all the Java technologies and JVM languages really -- the idea behind it being to create a set of standard questions/answers one needs to answer before deciding which of the Java frameworks and languages to use when starting a project.
For instance:

- if quick prototyping is needed and it consists of a lot of front end screens -- should something like Grails be considered first?
- Groovy vs Scala vs Java -- when and where to use one versus the other?
- why choose Spring MVC over Struts -- and maybe performance hits recorded for each?
- should the throughput of data/transaction influence such a decision and if so how?
- "Standard" ways of scaling out applications with each of the above

I guess the list can grow quite a lot -- this is obviously just a first "go" at this...

Answer (score 2):

**Overview of the current industry as those familiar with its breadth see it.  And where they see it in five or ten years.**

The audience for this event are experienced developers.  A lot of developers, though, have deep knowledge in certain areas and may not be familiar with the larger community.

My suggestion, then, is a survey of the modern programming languages and frameworks, leveraging a compare and contrast model, and their uses in the current marketplace.

Any developer can, of course, google this question and find myriad responses, but I feel the speakers at this conference will have a unique and interesting perspective on what is, and what may be in the future.

**Note:** I want to see data and curves here.

Answer (score 2):

The role of code reviews and security models (and other process-related issues) in startups and small companies.

Answer (score 2):

**Google App Engine**

More please....

Answer (score 1):

### **Microsoft Surface**

Developing multi-touch enabled applications for [Microsoft Surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface).

Answer (score 1):

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about)

New features in 3.1, best practices, [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data), Spring AOP vs AspectJ, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Impact of touch screen and small hand-held computers on programming

1. What IDE do I need for programming on my driod / assembling and deploying?
2. How to use my hand-held to develop more stuff on it

Answer (score 1):

### Massive, Dapper, and MicroORMs

Breakout topic, since Rob Conery probably can't speak at *every* event. Probably.

Answer (score 0):

FPGA and how it is being used in low-latency trading systems.

Comment: If you said programming techniques and strategies for low latency domains (e.g. trading systems) I would vote up - but not as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

[NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL), [Sass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29), [SproutCore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SproutCore), and [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

Comment: should be separate answers...

Answer (score 0):

### GWT and WindowBuilder

Google Web Toolkit can be used with or without Google's App Engine. It allows you to create the client-code in java that it underneath compiled into javascript.

WindowBuilder is a user interface builder tool that closely integrates with GWT,  but also with desktop application level UI libraries like Swing and SWT.

Answer (score 0):

**CQRS and Event Sourcing**

See *[CQRS and Event Sourcing](http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/cqrs-and-event-sourcing-synergy/)* for more details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Less software

It would be interesting to see how developers would give up their lust on building a solution with the most sophisticated and new and cool stack around, and build it with the pure minimum that gets the job done.

Less layers, less of a concept, less code*, less CPU, less technology. This would probably look like the 20% that do the most of the work without the 80% of bells and whistles.

Less code doesn't necessary means using shorter method/variable names or minification of some sort, it is closer to the "less of a concept" thing.

The idea is to challenge us to think a little in the opposite direction of the inertia to Web 3.0, clouds and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Writing applications that can make, recieve and interact with phone calls using Python, C#, etc

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby on Rails Best Practices

The framework has been out in the wild for a long time. Best practices that top developers in the field follow to make their apps.

Answer (score 0):

Qt and QML

Anyone using this? http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

## Object Normalization

"Everybody" knows about database normalization, but how about [Object Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476422/object-normalization)?

I've studied it for years, have some insights, and have decided that it's better to share them than take them to the grave. I can demonstrate much of the theory in a practical way by refactoring a really awful PHP script live. Sounds thrilling, I know, but it can give one a SOLID GRASP of object-oriented principles in a unifying framework - and the theory/practice has some surprisingly powerful implications.

It's probably too late to propose this for 2011. But what the heck. Dev Days DC is still months away!