# Bug/error on display on photo.stackexchange.com when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, specific-site

I see this bug on [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/): (only when not logged in)

> [image: menu garbled]

When hover mouse on:

> [image: mouse over corrects it]

I use Firefox in Windows 8, both are using auto update. I report this so that you can be noticed and fix this.

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome so it's not browser specific.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: check, then the tag can go. :-P

Comment: In addition, is there no way to report a bug without making it a question?

Comment: @Ooker: that's how we report bugs here.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of [Ask question/unanswered links are superimposed when logged out on the main site](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/q/4448)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: cause I don't ask any question. Anyway, should reporters have some thanked reputation? Just kidding XD

Comment: @Ooker: sure, we are bending the Q&A model a little, but so far this has worked out great. On *normal*, per-site Meta sites, you don't get reputation, btw. Only here on Meta.SE is reputation still enabled.

Comment: @Ooker: see [Should Stack Exchange Inc promote its pet projects on meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239096) for some background reading on the history of Meta.

Comment: oh come on, I just have a little kidding, don't you need to downvote me.

Answer (score 3):

This only applies to *anonymous users*. When logged in the link is positioned correctly.

This is caused by the following CSS rule:

```css
#header.headeranon, #hmenus .askquestion {
    top: 92px
}
```

which overrides

```css
.askquestion {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 114px;
}
```

As soon as you are logged in the first no longer applies. Clearly the first one assumes there are fewer links active when not logged in, and that assumption is incorrect. It should probably just be removed altogether.