# "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, tour

The [MSE tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) has this text:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

It's probably an oversight and copied from the regular site tours. Can it be reworded/removed?

Right above that text, there's this:

> So each community has a meta to discuss site-specific issues, and Meta Stack Exchange is for conversations about problems and ideas that affect the whole network.

Don't they contradict eachother?

Comment: What do you propose instead?  What problem do you have with what's there?

Comment: Guess the main confusion is from the word "discussion"? Discussions here (and on any Meta site) are meant to be focused and constructive, and those which are not will be closed.

Comment: @Servy how about ["This site is not all about getting answers. It's a discussion forum. There's chit-chat."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239096/165773)

Comment: @ShadowWizard indeed. I've expanded my post.

Answer (score 6):

It's still a rule for this site, even if it's less strictly enforced than on other sites. You will notice comments getting purged and/or moved to chat if they get totally off-topic, though we try to allow for a little bit of fun every now and then.

MSE is still focused on questions and answers, just a little more broadly than the main q&a sites.

Comment: Well, strictly-speaking, MSE *is* a discussion forum. Built on software explicitly not designed for discussion, but...

Comment: Could you tag this as by-design?

Answer (score 2):

### New answer

So... I've changed my point since and *even forgot that I had understood Meta in the different way before.* How? I don't know. Moreover, I've written [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260095/the-meta-is-being-both-discussion-and-not-a-discussion-site), which duplicated this one and *contradicted* with my old point of view.

Now, I don't think that on Meta, any question is about getting answers. Example? The bugs are often reported, but when reporting bug, a user is not asking for something generally. They are waiting for the official response, or for someone, who would say arguments for / against the bug fix.

Another example? Relatively often, we get new features, which are in the most cases accompanied with the feedback thread. I've said *thread*, because when announcing features, developers are not waiting for the *answers* (as we understand them on the non-meta communities), but for the feedback. Also, feature requests. They often lead to the discussion and certainly can't be *answered* in the way we are used to.

Conclusion is, I don't think that the Meta is not a discussion site. It's not really a forum though, but it's certainly made for discussions. And not always to get the answers, which ultimately applies only to the [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions.

### Old answer (my old point of view):

I think that current message is good.

> This site is all about getting answers.

yeah, isn't it? Or you don't want your questions to be answered?

> It's not a discussion forum.

yes, it isn't. Because "we prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed."

> There's no chit-chat.

This is quite arguable, I think :D