# The Meta is being both discussion and not a discussion site

Tags: bug, meta, tour

At the beginning of the tour we see:

> Meta Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites.

Fine. Then we look a bit further...

> The guidance on all our Q&A sites explicitly disallows meta-discussion, to reduce clutter and noise. There's no chit-chat; just questions and answers.

In this case it sounds like the rule which applies to MSE also, which would  not be correct. Sometimes it's about fixing bugs or implementing feature requests, etc.

And:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Yeah, not a forum, no chit-chat... Though as it's the Meta, it's a discussions site. Probably it should be reword a bit, needs more meta.

Comment: Eh, someone's definitely thinking this wording is correct...

Comment: It does contradict itself. Especially under the "is different - here's how" as where it tells users why it's different contradicts what it just told them.

Comment: Some people just don't like bugs